# display max and min number from user inputted numbers c++

Tags: c++

```
# include <iostream>
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int main()
{
    int numUserInt;         // Number of integers the user inputs
    int integers;
    int number;
    int maxNumber = 0;
    int minNumber = 0;

    // Get the number of integers
    cout << "How many integers would you like to enter?" << endl;
    cin  >> numUserInt;
    cout << "Please enter " << numUserInt << " integers." << endl;

    integers = 1;

    while (integers <= numUserInt)
    {
        cin >> number;

        if (numUserInt == 1)
            maxNumber = minNumber = number;

        if (number > maxNumber) 
            maxNumber = number;

        if (number < minNumber)
            minNumber = number;

        integers++;
    }

    cout << "min: " << minNumber << endl;
    cout << "max: " << maxNumber << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For a homework assignment I am supposed to ask a user "How many integers they would like to enter" and then find the Max and min number from the amount without using arrays. For the most part my program works, however when the user let's say enters -6 -6 the output is min: -6 and max: 0. I want this to say the min and max is -6 but I have no idea how to do this with making the rest of the code work. Anybody out there know of a way to do this?

Comment: Typical way to do this is to make the initial max value the minimum integer value, and vice versa for the initial min.

Comment: If you're allowed to, consider using [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) (given that it's homework, you may not be, but look it up anyway, so you'll know what to do when/if a similar problem arises in real life).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works exactly as intended, if you replace
`if (numUserInt == 1)`
by
`if (integers == 1)`.

That way, the recommendation from comment and other answers,
to init min and max with first input,
is implemented.

Output:

```
How many integers would you like to enter?
2
Please enter 2 integers.
-6
-6
min: -6
max: -6
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the value of both the `min` and `max` variable to the initial input then compare the `min` and `max` to what the user inputs each time to check if an update is neeeded.